Computing the Abelian invariants of a subgroup of a f.g. Abelian group
We have a f.g. Abelian group $A$ given as a direct sum of $N$ cyclic subgroups $C_{k_j}=\langle x_j\rangle$, with $k_j\in \{2,\dots,\infty\}$, $1\leq j  \leq N$, and the associated homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}^N\to A$.  Let $B\leq A$ be subgroup given by generators $g_i=\sum_j u_{ij} x_j$, $1\leq i\leq n$, and $u_{ij}\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then $B=\phi(\hat{B})$, and $\hat{B}$ may be computed by taking the SNF of the matrix $U:=(u_{ij})$.
EDIT: more precisely, $U$ is a presentation of the preimage of $A/B$ under $\phi$.
How does one compute the SNF of $B$ ? As the SNF is polynomial-time computable, by e.g. Kannan–Bachem algorithm, one expects this problem to have a polynomial-time algorithm, too.
For instance, here is an example in the answer by @derek-holt
gap> A:=DirectProduct(CyclicGroup(4),CyclicGroup(8),CyclicGroup(16));;
gap> Index(A,Subgroup(A,[A.1,A.3,A.6]));
1
gap> x1:=A.1;; x2:=A.3;; x3:=A.6;; # these are the 3 gens of A
gap> B:=Subgroup(A,[x1*x2^2*x3^2,x1^2*x2*x3^4]);
Group([ f1*f4*f7, f2*f3*f8 ])
gap> AbelianInvariants(B);
[ 8, 8 ]
gap> AbelianInvariants(A/B);
[ 8 ]
gap> M:=[[1,2,2],[2,1,4],[4,0,0],[0,8,0],[0,0,16]];
[ [ 1, 2, 2 ], [ 2, 1, 4 ], [ 4, 0, 0 ], [ 0, 8, 0 ], [ 0, 0, 16 ] ]
gap> Display(M);
[ [   1,   2,   2 ],
  [   2,   1,   4 ],
  [   4,   0,   0 ],
  [   0,   8,   0 ],
  [   0,   0,  16 ] ]
gap> Display(HermiteNormalFormIntegerMat(M));
[ [  1,  0,  2 ],
  [  0,  1,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  8 ],
  [  0,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  0 ] ]
gap> Display(SmithNormalFormIntegerMat(M));
[ [  1,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  1,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  8 ],
  [  0,  0,  0 ],
  [  0,  0,  0 ] ]


$B$ is not a matrix, so it is not clear what you mean by the SNF of $B$. Presumably you want to calculate the abelian invariants of the subgroup $B$ of $A$? You could do that by computing the Hermite Normal Form of a matrix defining generators of $\hat{B}$, giving you free generators of $\hat{B}$, then you can express the generators of $\ker(\phi)$ in terms of these free generators, which will enable you to do an SNF computation to find the abelian invariants of $B$.

$B$ is given by the matrix $U=(u_{ij})$, so one can think of a modified SNF computation for $U$, which takes into account that its columns correspond to $C_{k_j}$'s.

How does one express the generators of $\ker \phi$ in terms of the free gens of $\hat{B}$ ?

By solving linear equations over the integers, which can be done in polynomial time. I am not an expert on this subject, and I don't know whether the method I describe is the most efficient, but it does provide a polynomial-time algorithm. I could do an example, but I will wait to see if anyone else answers.

$\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}} \DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$Here is how to do it (probably the same as Derek Holt, but let me explicitly write the complete procedure).
Let $A$ be a finitely generated Abelian group, given by a presentation $\Z^r \stackrel{k}{\to} \Z^g \stackrel{g}{\to} A \to 0$. The presentation is given by the matrix $K$ of the map $k\colon \Z^r \to \Z^g$. From this we can obtain a standard presentation of $A$ (as a direct sum of cyclic groups) by computing the SNF of $K$, yielding a new presentation $\Z^N \to \Z^N \to A \to 0$, where the matrix of $\Z^N \to \Z^N$ is now a diagonal matrix with the usual divisibility condition.
So to obtain a standard presentation, it suffices to compute any presentation and then apply an SNF.
Now add a subgroup $B\le A$, given by a set of generators, i.e. by a map $s\colon \Z^{g'} \to A$ whose image is $B$. This map, in practice, is given by the expression of the generators of $B$ in terms of the generators of $A$, i.e. by a lift $\tilde{s}\colon \Z^{g'} \to \Z^g$ of $s$, i.e. by its matrix $S$. We would like to compute an arbitrary presentation of $B$, and for this it suffices to compute generators for the kernel of the map $s\colon \Z^{g'}\to A$. This is the same as the preimage under $\tilde{s}$ of $\ker g = \im k$. This can be computed by an HNF as follows. The concatenation $(S|K)$ of the matrices $S$ and $K$ is the matrix of the map $\tilde s\oplus k \colon \Z^{g'}\oplus \Z^k \to \Z^g$. The projection on $\Z^{g'}$ of $\ker (\tilde s\oplus k)$ is the desired preimage. In terms of matrices, this kernel is generated by the first zero columns of the HNF of $(S|K)$, and the projection means truncating these columns, leaving only the first $g'$ coordinates; the resulting matrix $K'$ is a generating matrix for the kernel of $s\colon \Z^{g'}\to A$, i.e. yields a presentation $\Z^{r'} \stackrel{k'}{\to} \Z^{g'} \stackrel{s}{\to} B \to 0$ of $B$.

Thanks! I  fixed a typo, and then it  indeed appears to be a nice explanation of Derek's computations (modulo replacing columns by rows)

Here is an example (chosen more or less at random) of the procedure that I described in my comment. Let $$A=\frac{\mathbb Z}{4{\mathbb Z}} \oplus \frac{\mathbb Z}{8{\mathbb Z}}  \oplus \frac{\mathbb Z}{16{\mathbb Z}},$$ and let $B$ be the subgroup spanned by  the images in $A$ of $(1,2,2)$ and $(2,1,4)$.
So the subgroup $\hat{B}$ of ${\mathbb Z}^3$ of which $B$ is the image is spanned by vectors
$$(1,2,2), (2,1,4), (4,0,0),(0,8,0),(0,0,16).$$
The matrix defining $\hat{B}$ and its (row) Hermite Normal Form are
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&2&2\\2&1&4\\4&0&0\\0&8&0\\0&0&16\end{array}\right),\hspace{1cm}\left(\begin{array}{ccc}1&0&2\\0&1&0\\0&0&8\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{array}\right).$$
So $\hat{B}$ is freely generated by $(1,0,2)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,0,8)$.
Now $\ker(\phi)$ is generated by $(4,0,0)$, $(0,8,0)$ and $(0,0,16)$, and by solving linear equations over the integers, we  find
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
(4,0,0) &=& 4(1,0,2) + 0(0,1,0) -(0,0,8)\\
(0,8,0) &=& 0(1,0,2) + 8(0,1,0)+ 0(0,0,8)\\
(0,0,16) &=& 0(1,0,2) + 0(0,1,0) +2(0,0,8)
\end{eqnarray*}.$$
So we need to find the Smith Normal Form of the matrix
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccr}4&0&-1\\0&8&0\\0&0&2\end{array}\right),\hspace{5mm} {\rm which\ is}\hspace{5mm}
\left(\begin{array}{ccr}1&0&0\\0&8&0\\0&0&8\end{array}\right),$$
and we conclude that $$B \cong \frac{\mathbb Z}{8{\mathbb Z}}  \oplus \frac{\mathbb Z}{8{\mathbb Z}}.$$

Isn't "the matrix defining $\hat{B}$" a presentation for $A/B$ ?

I am not sure what you mean. The rows of the matrix are generators of the subgroup $\hat{B}$ of ${\mathbb Z}^3$, so I guess you could think of it as a presentation of ${\mathbb Z}^3/\hat{B}$ but (if I have understood your original question correctly) that's not what we are trying to calculate.

The HNF of this matrix tells us that it is a presentation of $\mathbb{Z}/8\mathbb{Z}=A/B$.

Thinking of this matrix as a spanning set of the kernel of a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^3$.

I am trying to give this computation a coordinate-free interpretation, and it should be computing a presentation for $B$. It should be a matrix so that together with the one we talk about they span the whole $\mathbb{Z}^3$, and the intersection of their spans is $\ker\phi$.

The result of the computation in this example is $A/B \cong {\mathbb Z}/8{\mathbb Z} \oplus {\mathbb Z}/8{\mathbb Z} $, not ${\mathbb Z}/8{\mathbb Z}$. The matrix for $\hat{B}$ shows that ${\mathbb Z}^3/\hat{B} \cong {\mathbb Z}/8{\mathbb Z}$, but that's not what you are trying to compute.

mea culpa, I formulated my question badly.

I have $B=\langle g_1,..., g_n\rangle$. I wrote that the SNF of the matrix obtainded from expressions for the $g_i$'s as words in generators of A computes $\hat{B}$ - that was not correct, as it computes $\widehat{A/B}$.

I added GAP computations for your example in the question, and they show that $A/B$ and  $B$ are as I state, and not as you state.

Your GAP computation gives $[8,8]$ for  the abelian invariants of $B$, which agrees with what I wrote. I thought that was what you were trying to compute. I continure to think that the source of all this confusion is that your question "How does one compute the SNF for $B$"? does not make sense. Matrices have an SNF, not groups.
